# E/LB: fail to open file: No such file or directory - Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, local-storage

I try to display whatsapp Status images from the File directory ('/storage/emulated/0/WhatsApp/Media/.Statuses').
But there do not appear any image. Console showing => **"FAIL TO Open File: no Such File or Directory"**.

also i change The File Path to DCIM ('/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/'), and it was possible to display the image.

What can be the problem here?

***My code:***

```
final Directory _photoDir = new Directory(
      '/storage/emulated/0/Android/media/com.whatsapp/WhatsApp/Media/.Statuses/');

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (!Directory("${_photoDir.path}").existsSync()) {
      return Container(
        child: Center(
          child: Text("install WhatsApp\nsee your friends status here!"),
        ),
      );
    } else {
      print(_photoDir.path);
      var imageList = _photoDir
          .listSync()
          .map((item) => item.path)
          .where((item) => item.endsWith(".jpg"))
          .toList(growable: false);
      print(imageList.length);

      if (imageList.length > 0) {
        return GridView.builder(
          gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
            crossAxisCount: 3,
            crossAxisSpacing: 5.0,
            mainAxisSpacing: 5.0,
          ),
          itemCount: imageList.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            String imgPath = imageList[index];
            return Hero(
                tag: imgPath,
                child: Image.file(
                  File(imgPath),
                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                ));
          },
        );
      } else {
        return Container(
          child: Center(
            child: Text("Sorry No Status found..!"),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
  }
}
```

***AndroidManifest.xml***

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<!-- Permissions options for the `storage` group -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

***Get the Permistion***

```
  Future<void> requestLocationPermission() async {
    final status = await Permission.storage.request();
    Permission.photos.request();

    if (status == PermissionStatus.granted) {
      print('Permission Granted');
    } else if (status == PermissionStatus.denied) {
      print('Permission denied');
    } else if (status == PermissionStatus.permanentlyDenied) {
      print('Permission Permanently Denied');
      await openAppSettings();
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    requestLocationPermission();
  }
```

Comment: Use File.exists() and if it exists also File.canRead() before you try to use the file.

Comment: You do this on an Android 11+ device?

Comment: yes i run this on anroid 11.

Answer (score 0):

I think that. Your selected directory is a hidden file directory. so you cant get that file. I am not sure try another directory.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32997828)